# How are interfaces like Runnable unique?

Tags: java

My understanding of interfaces in java/android is they're used to ensure the member functions are used. E.g. like [Runnable](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runnable) which ensures implemented classes use the `run()` function within `Runnable`.

However, how are these functions unique? Say there's another interface like `Runnable` with only 1 member function - let's call it `Passable` - and it has 1 member function called `pass()`.

How exactly are these 2 interfaces different at all (apart from having different names)?

Or is the names what make them different? E.g. Android detects if the class is called `Runnable` then it does something different.

Comment: Note that some interfaces (like `Serializable`) don't declare any methods *at all*. It's all about the naming (which is a tiny bit more complicated but mostly reduces to "the fully-qualified class name").

Comment: So what is the effect of the name of the class being `Serializable`? Which system/function detects that name and behaves differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two interfaces can have the same "content", like the same number of methods and matching method signatures.

Still they are *different* because of different names. You might even have interfaces (or classes!) that have the same name, to only deviate in the package name. There are for example multiple different classes out there named Pair.

But interfaces don't determine which methods are called. You write code that picks a method and invokes that, and the fact that some class implements a specific interface simply tells you: "OK, it is a Runnable, so I can and probably want to invoke its run method".

You see, Java is a statically compiled language. That means that you use types to communicate intent. You have some piece of code that is supposed to be called on its own by other code in a uniform, maybe multi threaded context? Then you consider putting that code into a Runnable. That is all there is to this.

Comment: So there's nothing unique about these interfaces - they just provide the right setup (number of methods and method signatures) for you to execute the **body** of these functions - which is where the real difference lies?

Comment: One can see it that way. Interfaces are just "names" describing a set of functionality.

Comment: How does it being a `Runnable` create it's own thread? Where's the source code for that?

Comment: A runnable by itself doesn't come with a new thread. Runnables are just a "container" that most often gets used with threads.

Answer (score 2):

Interfaces are not used to define what methods are called.

One of the main function of interfaces is to separate API from implementation.
This means for example that any class that implements Runnable can be used to run in a parallel thread.
The other is to define the type of a class beyond the scope of inheritance.

A quote from effective java:

> The Java programming language provides two mechanisms for defining a
>   type that permits multiple implementations: interfaces and abstract
>   classes. The most obvious difference between the two mechanisms is
>   that abstract classes are permitted to contain implementations for
>   some methods while interfaces are not. A more important difference is
>   that to implement the type defined by an abstract class, a class must
>   be a subclass of the abstract class. Any class that defines all of the
>   required methods and obeys the general contract is permitted to
>   implement an interface, regardless of where the class resides in the
>   class hierarchy. Because Java permits only single inheritance, this
>   restriction on abstract classes severely constrains their use as
>   type definitions

By implementing the Runnable interface, you aren't telling your code that the run method should be called. You are telling the code that your class is a type of Runnable or literally spelt out, your class is runnable.

One example usage of this could if you were to an abstract class: `Plant`.
Now you would use this class to define some common properties of plants (such as they need soil), then you would create its subclasses `Potato`, `Rosemary`, `Dandelion`

Now say you want to indicate which of these plants is edible, you could create an intermediary subclass called `EdiblePlant` that is a subclass of Plant and the superclass of the edible classes. `EdiblePlant` has a method called `eat()`, thus you can eat all edible plants.

Now if you want to also have a class `Animal` and its subclasses `Dog`, `Cow`, `Pig`.
You would again have to indicate which one is edible by a new intermediary class `EdibleAnimal`, which again would have an `eat()` method.

I guess it doesn't seem that much work but now what if you want to have `Human`, who eats?

You would have to have both `Human.eat(EdibleAnimal animal);` method and `Human.eat(EdiblePlant plant)` method. Since we can eat both of those.

Instead, we could define an interface `Edible` that would have a method `eat()`. This type indicates that Classes (plants and animals) that implement this type can, in fact, be eaten.

Since now we have a common type for edible things we can simply have one eat method on Human, `Human.eat(Edible food)`

Since we now have a separated interface and implementation we no longer how to think about refactoring/adding new methods to `Human`, we only have to appropriately implement the `Edible` type.

I would recommend reading up on how Java works, before starting with Android development, if you don't you can form these kinds of bad theoretical models of how things work such as `interface determines what methods will be called` and then when it will clash with the actual workings of Java you will be frustrated and won't understand why what you wrote doesn't work as 'expected'.

Comment: Thanks for the example. I don't think my perspective is wrong (may have worded it wrong). Interfaces provide a framework of methods/variables for classes to implement. It allows for multiple classes to use the same interface instead of making multiple subclasses. Is this wrong?

Comment: @Zorgan I guess the correct wording would be that it allows for classes to be of multiple types, which the inheritance doesn't allow since you can only have one parent.
As I said it also helps separate implementation from API, one example of this is the Logging API, you can use any of the implementations (Logback, Log4j2, etc.) and then change them because the methods are defined in the interfaces and those don't change.